# Inno Setup - Prevent installer from adding registry entries and being included in programs/features

Tags: inno-setup

I am not 100% sure how Inno Setup deals with the registry, but from what I can tell, it adds a few items to the registry even though I do not have any code under `[Registry]`. This is something we would like to eliminate if possible and we would also like it to not show up in the programs/features menu (which I'm assuming is directly related to the registry). I am unsure how to approach this problem because I can't see where Inno Setup is directly doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate on @Robert's answer:

Setting [`CreateUninstallRegKey`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_createuninstallregkey) to `no` prevents Inno Setup from creating uninstallation registry keys. So the application won't be listed in *Add/Remove Programs* control panel. It still can be uninstalled though by locating the `unins000.exe` (default name) in the application program folder and running it. Note that the registry key created by `CreateUninstallRegKey=yes` is basically a simple reference to the `unins000.exe`.

Setting [`Uninstallable`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallable) to `no` disables possibility to uninstall the application at all. So not only it behaves as if `CreateUninstallRegKey=no`, but does not even "install" the `unins000.exe`.

So you want the `CreateUninstallRegKey=no`.

Answer (score 2):

In the `[Setup]` section, add:

```
Uninstallable=no
```

Or:

```
CreateUninstallRegKey=no
```

Dependent on your requirements.

Comment: So maybe I am a little confused. Is the role of uninstaller to remove the registry entries and the listing in the program/features menu and remove the files? I would still like an uninstaller, but something that just removes the files (because there shouldn't be any registry entries anyways).

Comment: I have updated my answer. There are two different options dependent on your requirements. The documentation/help file explains both options. Note that entries in the Add/Remove Programs are created in the Registry.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at both and I believe the second one will fulfill my requirements.. I'll play with both though